# Bootstrap width class/attribute not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4.5 (with NextJS 11.1 on ReactJS 18.2)

In the below snippet, per inspection with Chrome dev tools, the divWithNoWidthSet div is not getting its width attribute set despite having w-80 and/or mw-80 class. I can see the class attribute in generated source, but no width attribute exists in the inspection panel.

I saw posts on SO where the cause of similar behavior was the div containing an image with img-fluid class, but such is not the case here. Any help appreciated--thanks!

```
<div className="m-auto w-30 rounded d-block" style={{ height: '300px', backgroundColor: 'whitesmoke'}}  >
  <div style={{ height: '150px'}} >
    <a href={...} target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src={...`}  className="img-fluid h-150 hm-150 mw-50 d-block m-auto" alt={...} /> </a>
  </div>
  <a href={...} target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <div id="divWithNoWidthSet" className="w-80 mw-80 text-center m-auto p-3" style={{border: '1px solid red'}}>
      <h5>{...}</h5>
      <p>{...}</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on official [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/sizing/):

> Width and height utilities are generated from the `$sizes` Sass map in
> `_variables.scss`. **Includes support for `25%`, `50%`, `75%`, `100%`, and `auto` by default.** Modify those values as you need to generate different
> utilities here.

If you want to use the class `w-80` then you need to add it in `_variables.scss`. By default, there's no `w-80` class.

Comment: Thanks! I need to get out of habit of skimming through the documentation!